# When is tension inversely proportional to acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

So I have questions where 2 pulleys are present, and when one of them is fixed to a rigid support on one end, it is said that tension is inversely proportional to acceleration.

On the other hand, when the 2nd pulley is not fixed, this relationship isn't applying. Can someone tell why?

Comment: You will have to provide a better description of this system. A diagram would be good. What accelerations and tensions are you referring to? Since the second pulley is not fixed to anything is it in free fall? Is this one scenario with two pulleys or two separate scenarios with one pulley each?

Comment: @mathysics I'll add a diagram shortly